# VLC Media Player - Stopping it from reopening it's window after minimizing

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player

Situation:

VLC plays the video I want, without issues, I minimize the video so I can focus on other things while listening to the audio. The video ends and when I press the multimedia key to play the video again, the VLC window opens up and gets on top of all the other windows as the video starts playing. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I'd much rather just stay with the minimized icon on the systray on Windows 7 and only have the window open when I click it.

Note: the issue also happens when I stop the video with my multimedia keys and try to play it again, so I suspect is something that happens when the "Play" command is given.

Answer (score 0):

Open VLC media player and press Ctrl+p. It will open "preferences".

> Make sure  Pause playback when minimized is unchecked

[image: Refer this picture]

Comment: I have that configurated as the image shows, the behavior still happens...

Comment: "Stopping it from reopening it's window after minimizing" - This appears to be a long-standing issue, see https://superuser.com/questions/379293/how-to-keep-vlc-player-in-minimized-mode (2014), and it's happening to me, 3+ years later. "Pause playback when minimized" is related to minimizing, but that's about it. @GuilhermeVargas is using Windows 7, I'm using Xubuntu. I've disabled video, tried combinations of --qt-*, dug into my WM settings, etc., still no resolution. The best I can do is invoke the cmd line interface with an unused/invalid display to avoid the GUI entirely. Good luck GV.