# Is there any way to move VLC media player to system tray while a music/video is being played?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vlc-media-player, notification-area

I was wondering if there's any way to move VLC media player to the system tray while a music/video is being played?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep VLC player in minimized mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/379293/how-to-keep-vlc-player-in-minimized-mode)

Comment: The duplicate is not very suitable as I found a way to minimize it very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

When playing a file on VLC media player, it will appear on the system tray as well.

In order to minimize the windows, right-click on VLC logo in the system tray and select the option "Hide VLC media player in taskbar":

[image]

You can also define if your player should autoraise for a specific content like video:

[image]