# How to stop VideoLAN to switch to VideoLAN window when in playlist

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am using VideoLAN on Windows to play a list of videos (Ctrl + L) in the background - I am only interested in listening the sounds of those videos.

But VideoLAN will switch to the VideoLAN window everytime it plays a new video in the playlist. And that is really annoying because I need it to play videos in background so I can keep doing what I am working at (editing text files, writing a blog etc).

Is it possible to stop VideoLAN to switch to the VideoLAN window?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I have seen that duplicate post before answering, but it's old from 2012 and its answers don't apply nowadays. You might consider re-opening this post.

Comment: @harrymc https://superuser.com/a/1426631/337631 still applies and is essentially the same as your answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill: That interface no longer exists, so no point in anyone searching for it.

Comment: @harrymc Sure it does. Screen shot from my PC https://i.imgur.com/e2jjd5u.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Enter VLC *Tools > Preferences*
- At the bottom-left click on "All" for "Show settings"
- Expand *Interface > Main interfaces* and click on Qt
- At the bottom set the option for "When to raise the interface" to Never.

"Raise the interface" means that when VLC is in the background, and it reaches
the end of a media file and goes on to the next one, the focus will go to the VLC
window and bring it forward.